# Why does sbt fail with sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency for Spark 2.0.0 and Scala 2.9.1?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm trying to run a sample scala code using spark_submit using SBT. And this is my scala code -

```
import scala.math.random

import org.apache.spark._

/** Computes an approximation to pi */
object SparkPi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
    val n = 100000 * slices 
    val count = spark.parallelize(1 to n, slices).map { i =>
      val x = random * 2 - 1
      val y = random * 2 - 1
      if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
    }.reduce(_ + _)
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

### And this is my sparksample.sbt file -

```
name := "Spark Sample"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
```

But when i run SBT and package command im getting the below error

> [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.9.1;2.0.0: not found

My scala version is **2.9.1** and my spark version is **2.0.0**.

I'm following the below site for running spark_submit using sbt -

https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/apache-spark-cluster-part-2-deploy-a-scala-program-to-spark-cluster/

Answer (score 2):

> unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.9.1;2.0.0: not found

There's no Scala 2.9.1-based dependency of Spark 2.0.0 and hence the error message.

sbt could not have been more correct. The blog post is **super** old and you'd better forget about it immediately (I really wished the blog post had not existed any more). Please use the [Spark official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) instead and your best bet would be to start from [Quick Start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html).

---

Quick workaround is to replace `scalaVersion := "2.9.1"` in `sparksample.sbt` to:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

and you should be fine.

**PROTIP** Rename `sparksample.sbt` to `build.sbt` (and your teammates will love you again ;-))

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know how to reason about this problem, which happens often in development on the JVM.

In the Scala ecosystem where binary compatibility is a concern, it is common for dependencies to have `artifactId`s named with the version of Scala they were compiled with. For example, the latest version of Spark has these coordinates:

```
groupId: 'org.apache.spark'
artifactId: 'spark-core_2.11'
version: '2.1.0'
```

The `artifactId` indicates that this dependency was compiled with Scala 2.11.

Meanwhile, SBT offers shorthand so you don't have to append the Scala version you've already specified to every dependency listed in `libraryDependencies`. It does so with the `%%` between the `groupId` and `artifactId`. (You can use a single `%` if you want to be explicit about versions, but that isn't common among SBT users.)

Put all this together, and you are implying in your `build.sbt` that your project has a dependency with coordinates `org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.9.1:2.0.0`. But the error says SBT can't find one.

When that happens, there are two possibilities. The dependency doesn't exist, or you need to add the repository where it does to `build.sbt`. With something available as widely as Spark--and you can confirm this in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html)--you will know Spark is available from Maven Central. As the [search for the artifact you specified](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.spark%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spark-core_2.9.1%22%20AND%20v%3A%222.0.0%22) shows, it doesn't exist.

So then it comes time to check the documentation to figure out which artifact you need instead. Or you can check Maven Central again or [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11), which I generally prefer, to find the artifacts available for the combination of Scala version *and* Spark version you prefer to work with.

In the end, you will find Scala 2.11.x, which is *not* the latest version of Scala but the latest version of Scala that Spark works with, is what you want--probably 2.11.8. And if your environment permits, go with the latest version of Spark too, which is 2.1.0:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0", 
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no 2.9.1 version of spark-core 2.0, see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark
Scala 2.9.1 is pretty old and has many compatibility problems with 2.10 and upper versions. You should try at least Scala 2.10.